# How to go back to an earlier point in a Python program?

Tags: python

```
#this is my very first python attempt

name = raw_input("What is your name?")

if len("string") > 0:
    print "Hello %s, Let's be friends!" % name
else:
    print "Sorry, what was that?"

print ""
print name + ","
lor = raw_input("You come to a crossroads, left or right?")

if lor == "left":
    print "You went left"
elif lor == "right":
    print "You went right"
else:
    print "That's not a direction."
```

This is my first code. Is there a way to make a person choose right or left again if they wrote in something other than right or left? (so basically take them back to the raw_input of lor)?

Comment: You're looking for a loop.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [Python flow control tools](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Comment: You need `if len(name) > 0:` at the top, not `len("string")`

Comment: The python way is just: `if len(name)`.

Comment: I used to write loads of code like this, in basic, 30 years ago :D

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl What about `if name`.

Comment: @Vorsprung:  It's a great way to start.

Comment: As an aside, `direction` would be a better variable name than `lor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `while` loop:

```
query = "You come to a crossroads, left or right?" 
lor = raw_input(query).strip().lower()
while lor not in ("left", "right"):
    print "That's not a direction."
    lor = raw_input(query).strip().lower()

if lor == "left":
    print "You went left"
else:
    print "You went right"
```

As others have pointed out in comments the `if` condition at the top should be: `if name`.

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
if name:
    print "Hello %s, Let's be friends!" % name
else:
    print "Sorry, what was that?"
```

Comment: Why not just set `lor = ''` before the loop?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl:  If `lor` was set to a blank string before the loop you would get the message `"That's not a direction."` on the first time through.

Comment: I know that, the message should be in an if at the end of the while.

Comment: It did work, but im faced with one more issue. When i type " right" with a space it doesnt accept it, even if I change it to have a space: `if lor == " right"`

Comment: @RheannaLamph use `str.strip` to remove trailing and leading whitespaces. See my updated solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is @Ashwini Chaudhary's answer, slightly changed.

```
question = "You come to a crossroads.  Go left or right?"
lor = raw_input(question)
while not "left".startswith(lor) and not "right".startswith(lor):
    print "That's not a direction."
    lor = raw_input(question)

if "left".startswith(lor):
    print "You went left"
else:
    print "You went right"
```

This change allows the user to type less than the whole word.  The user can go left by typing "l", "le", "lef", or "left".  Similarly the user can go right by typing "r", "ri", "rig", etc.

Also, since the question was duplicated I made a variable and used the variable twice.  That way if you change the question, you only need to change it in one place.

You could write a function that takes a question and a list of valid answers to the question, and then asks the question over and over in a loop until a valid answer was given.  Then the function would return the valid answer.  Also, the question can always return the full answer even if the user entered an abbreviation.  Here's code to do that:

```
def ask(question, lst_answers):
    if not question.endswith(' '):
        question += ' '

    while True:
        answer = raw_input(question).strip().lower()
        lst = [a for a in lst_answers if a.startswith(answer)]
        if len(lst) == 1:
            return lst[0]
        else:
            print "Please answer with one of: " + ' '.join(lst_answers)

answer = ask("You come to a crossroads.  Go left or right?", ["left", "right"])
if answer == "left":
    print "You went left"
else:
    print "You went right"
```

This may look tricky, but actually this is the lazy way to do it.  We solved the basic problem in one place, and then your code can just call this function and rely on it to do the right thing.

The heart of the `ask()` function is a "list comprehension", where we make a list of all the answers that match an expression.  The expression is `a.startswith(answer)`, so we get a new list with all the answers that start with what the user typed.  Then we check to see if we got exactly one answer.  If we got zero answers, the user typed something weird.  If we got more than one answer, the user typed a short abbreviation but multiple words matched: for example if we accept answers of "left" or "look" and the user just typed "l".  If we got exactly one answer, we return that answer, which happily enough is the full answer and not the abbreviation that the user typed!

Comment: I think thats a little passed what I know. I just started learning python yesterday. I don't want to put anything in there that I don't understand yet

Comment: I don't want to be pushy.  If you aren't comfortable with this code, leave it for now.  But maybe remember this and come back to it later.  If you don't write a function like this, your adventure game will contain lots of extra code... then, when you go back and put in this function, you will see how your code gets smaller and simpler; and you will better appreciate how much functions like this can help you!

Comment: I wasn't saying I won't use it, just not YET, haha.